# Building a semi-discretionary system

Tags: equities, algorithmic-trading, machine-learning

I've been investing for the last 15 years in a weird Buffett/Soros way.
For the last few years I've been toying with the idea of modeling myself.

I want to build a 'stock screener' that will be able to suggest stocks based on:

- 13F (like Buffett).
- Stock repurchase.
- Inside trading.
- Expectations.
- Falling angels score.
- EV / EBIT.
- Company events (ceo left, class    action, ..)

Is there an existing framework that I can use to allow me to achieve this?
I'm a Python programmer (dayjob)

Thanks

EDIT:
I found this book- [Systematic Trading: A unique new method for designing trading and investing systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014J5LNSY) that also comes with the python [project](https://github.com/robcarver17/pysystemtrade).
I'm reading the book, so far looks promising

Comment: You might start (if you have not already done so) by investigating the capabilities of commercially available stock screeners such as Zacks Investment Research, FactSet or Refinitiv's QA Direct.

Answer (score 2):

Given you have a database that stores this data daily, you could write a short python script to apply your screening and email you the daily rankings or scores.

I think you can even do this in Excell if you have a Bloomberg or TR terminal. I am pretty sure that you can.

If you want to backtest the performance of such a strategy then I think using Quantopians platform is the best and easiest way to go.